# wso2 AM identitfy folder and script missing from dbscripts folder version 2.1.0

Tags: sql-server, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to configure the latest version of WSO2 AM 2.1.0 using a Microsoft SQL Server for its database on a windows server.

The databases have been created with user accounts and trying to start up the application with the start up flag auto create the tables.

the command I am running is: wso2server.bat -Dsetup

Some of the tables are created for the product but receive the following error during the start up on the console window. I have checked and the folder is missing from the distribution. Any help on a way forward?

```
[2017-08-09 11:24:47,614] ERROR - IdentityCoreServiceComponent Error occurred while populating identity configuration properties
org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityRuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Software\2.1\wso2am-2.1.0\bin\..\dbscripts\identity\mssql.sql (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityRuntimeException.error(IdentityRuntimeException.java:71)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.persistence.IdentityDBInitializer.executeSQLScript(IdentityDBInitializer.java:273)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.persistence.IdentityDBInitializer.createIdentityDatabase(IdentityDBInitializer.java:141)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.persistence.JDBCPersistenceManager.initializeDatabase(JDBCPersistenceManager.java:112)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.internal.IdentityCoreServiceComponent.activate(IdentityCoreServiceComponent.java:130)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:514)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.removePendingItem(CarbonServerManager.java:290)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.bundleChanged(PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:847)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Software\2.1\wso2am-2.1.0\bin\..\dbscripts\identity\mssql.sql (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.persistence.IdentityDBInitializer.executeSQLScript(IdentityDBInitializer.java:235)
        ... 30 more
```

Thanks,
Gary

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options.

1) Run database scripts manually on created databases, and start server **without** `-Dsetup`.

2) Go to `<APIM_HOME>/dbscripts/`. Make a copy of `apimgt` and name it as `identity`. Then start server with `-Dsetup`.